# Apply box-shadow to one background image in comma separated list of background images

Tags: html, css

on my site I have

```
body{
    background-image: url(http://placeholder/aaa.png), url(http://placeholder/bbb.png);
}
```

which allows me to have one background image overlaying another.

aaa.png is a smaller image being placed in the center over bbb.png

I want to apply a box-shadow to the top image, picture aaa.png in this example.

Currently I have tried

```
body{
    background-image: url(http://placeholder/aaa.png), url(http://placeholder/bbb.png);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px, 0 0 0px 0px
}
```

and also swapping the placements of the `0 0 10px 10px` to make sure that order wasn't an issue, but for some reason it is only applying thy box-shadow to the bottom image (bbb.png) (or it might be placing it to the farthest edges of the combined background image)

How can I make the box-shadow apply only to aaa.png

Comment: box-shadow has nothing to do with the background, it applies to the element regardless its background

Answer (score 0):

I checked online, and this example you provided should work, atleast it looks like it.

But okay, maybe try to take the other image, create a div put that small background picture as that div background, and then style it hoe you want, that should do the trick :)